# Не отображается статистика Chrome расширения (Показы и установки)

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension, статистика, extension

У chrome - расширения с определенной даты не отображается статистика показов и установок (то есть, значение установок и показов равно нулю.)
С чем это может быть связано? 
Расширение корректно отображается в магазине Chrome - расширений, устанавливал его на различных компьютерах, все ок, но установки и просмотры в статистике не показываются.

Скриншот со статистикой (проблема возникла с 13 декабря): 
[image: Скриншот показов и установок]

Статистика удалений отображается корректно.

Comment: Это баг. Разработчики Extension Dashboard уведомлены, но пока не решили проблема. Вы можете найти обсуждение проблемы тут: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/jAg8lzX9yjo

Comment: @Deliaz, понял, спасибо!